# Debian Stretch post-up change gateway to second interface

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

I have two interfaces on a Debian Stretch install where I want to change the default gateway after booting the box to the second interface. I have a working config from Jessie that I updated to reflect Stretch like:

```
# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens3
iface ens3 inet static
    address 1.2.3.4/24
    gateway 1.2.3.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

allow-hotplug ens9
iface ens9 inet static
    address 5.6.7.8
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 5.6.7.1
    post-up ip route change default via 5.6.7.1
    #post-up route del default gw 1.2.3.1 ens3
    #post-up route add default gw 5.6.7.1 ens9
```

The post-up route commands don't appear to work on Strech (but did on Jessie), and the post-up ip route change command doesn't work either, though if I run it later from command line like:

```
ip route change default via 5.6.7.1
```

It works fine. What am I doing wrong? I guess I could put it in a cron job to run 30 seconds after start, but why won't it work in my /etc/network/interfaces config file?